# How to create a singleton using enum if initializing the object involves checked exception handling

Tags: java, constructor, enums

***EDIT***

*Please note my question is more to understand if there is any best practice around it. The problem I am describing can be tackled many way, in fact I am handling it by throwing Runtime Exception. But is it the best practice? or should we fall back to  more conventional ways of Singleton creation using a static method and decoupling exception from object creation*

I am using enum to instantiate a singleton as prescribed in Effective Java

```
public enum MailApp { 
INSTANCE;   
private Gmail mailService;

private MailApp() {
    try {
        mailService = GoogleMailAppFactory.getGmailService();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is if I add throws like following

```
public enum MailApp {

INSTANCE;

 /** Application name. */

private Gmail mailService;

private MailApp() throws IOException {
    mailService = GoogleMailAppFactory.getGmailService();
}
```

This will not compile saying Unhandled Exception

I have taken a look at [How to throw an exception from an enum constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543903/how-to-throw-an-exception-from-an-enum-constructor)

I could not find any conclusive answer. So my question: What are the best practices for this? Is throwing an AssertionError  only way forward?

Thanks for your help

**Edit**

*My "MailApp" is only valid if we have a valid email service. In short I dont want to create an empty object. Could you please throw some light why this might be a bad idea and how this should be approached?*

Comment: whatis tour goal? how you want your application behave it  mailservice create exception on creation? that should be your first questio really. i suggest to handle exception inside constructor, and have additional method on singleton isAvailable

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to init a mail service within an enum?!

Comment: Uwe, for me MailService is just any Backend API.  My "GmailApp" is only valid if we have a valid email service. In short I dont want to create an empty object. Could you please throw some light why this might be a bad idea and how this should be approached? Also my enum is only for singleton, not per se a constant, as prescribed in Josh Bloch's Effective Java which is a bible for me and there lies the confusion :)

Comment: @UweAllner I agree, probably better off using a `Map<EnumeratedType, MailApp>`, where the `MailApp` is a wrapper around a specific singleton instance, possibly holding a `Weak Reference` to the connection. It would allow `mailerMap.get(GMAIL).send(message)`;

Comment: @vallismortis but how do you create the singleton?

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder Enumerated types are instantiated when they are loaded by the classloader, so if there were a problem connecting to any individual service, it would throw an exception immediately upon running the application. A better practice would be to de-couple the exception-raising method invocation from the enumerated type, so that any exceptions will be raised at appropriate times (such as sending/receiving a message).

Comment: @ vallismortis I totally get your point,.But I dont want to create an empty object and inject mailService. If I understand you correctly thats what you mean by decoupling. Moreover if you see Effective Java it says the best way to create a singleton is by using enum and I was trying to follow that. Now my object does not make sense without mailservice which I want to initialize in constructor. What I am trying to figure out is what should be the best practice. Should we fallback on more conventional way of creating singleton?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider rethrowhing ioexception as a RuntimeException.

Comment: Hi David, if you see I am throwing an assertionerror as a RuntimeException which is more kind of appropriate

Comment: I was not precise in my comment, what I meant is that you may want to re-throw the IOException as an unchecked exception (either a `RuntimeException` or a subclass of such) e.g.:  
    catch (IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

Comment: Ok, I understand you comment now, since `AssertionError` is unchecked why do you declare that `MailApp` throws IOException?

Answer (score 0):

COMPLEX EXAMPLE:

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public enum Gender {

     /** non mather */
     NONE(0,R.string.any),

    /** Male */
    MALE(1,R.string.male);

    private final int _rId;
    private final int _id;

    private Context _context;

    public void  setContext(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    private Gender(int id, int rId) {
        _id = id;
        _rId = rId;

        /** get context from setter */
        if(_context==null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Exception");
        }

    }

    /**
     * @return The string representation of this element in the enumeration.
     */
    public int getResId() {
        return _rId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public static Gender getById(int id ) {
        return byId.get(id);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return _context.getResources().getString(_rId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getName();
    }

    private static final Map<Integer, Gender> byId = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (Gender gender : Gender.values()) {
            if (byId.put(gender.getId(), gender) != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate id: " +gender.getId()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

- try implement Singletons by simply make an enum type with one element
- enum singleton guarantee that it's instance will be once per VM.

basicaly

```
public final class ISingleton {
    public final static ISingleton INSTANCE = new ISingleton(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Tomsaz, If you see my code I used the same concept using AssertionError

Comment: java.lang.Error And Errors are not meant to be caught They indicatiing about programming error.Imagine when we got OutOfMemoryError and you catch it while your app is still running.

Comment: Yep I get it. Good point, Thanks. Any other you can think of? Do you even think enum singleton is a good way to create Singleton?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually disagree with this approach specifically because of the issue you are dealing with.

I would implement singletons *if I have to* in the SE environment as follows:

```
public final class SingletonClass {
    private static SingletonClass INSTANCE;

    public SingletonClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private SingletonClass() throws WhateverException {
       ...
    }
    static {
       try {
           INSTANCE = new SingletonClass();
       } catch (WhateverException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
    }
}
```

The reason why I emphasize *if I have to* is because I try to avoid it in the first place because it is rare I would have only one of something.  And with the notion of Dependency Injection using CDI or Picocontainer which works on SE environments as well though CDI has a lot of baggage and a lot more confusing to diagnose compared to Picocontainer.

On an JEE6 environment I would use the `@javax.ejb.Singleton` annotation. That guarantees that there is only one instance in a clustered deployment without a lot of fuss.

To clarify why the above works:

- The static initializer only gets executed once [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe)
- Unless you're doing something really complicated, you would only have a single class loader to work with on SE.
- `enum`s are `Serializable` but there's no guarantee that your singleton class would/should be serializable.
- What you are building is a `class`, not an `enum`.  This is akin to having the constants in `interface` which is actually noted as a bad idea in the Effective Java book https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49572/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-an-interface-to-define-constants
- This also handles `RuntimeException` and `Error` such as `OutOfMemoryError` in a more predictable fashion in that it will automatically wrap the error in `ExceptionInInitializerError` which makes it more obvious what the error is.

Comment: Correct. the final one **What you are building is a class, not an enum** always used to bother me. I have been even reading using enum as singleton is at least a debatable idea. So the usecase I mentioned seems to me a perfect opportunity for me to ask for opinions in stackoverflow.

Comment: In addition, this handles Errors such as out of memory (I'll update the answer to note that)