# Why am I getting this compiler error (using enum as singleton)?

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I have the following class, which encapsulates some test data. I need only one instance of it, so I create an enum.

```
public enum ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings {
    INSTANCE; // Compiler error occurs here
    private final Map<String, IBuilding> buildingsByIds;
    ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings() throws ParserConfigurationException,
        SAXException, XPathExpressionException, IOException {
        this.buildingsByIds = composeBuildingsByIds(
            getBuildings(ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings.class)
        );
    }
    public Map<String, IBuilding> getBuildingsByIds() {
        return buildingsByIds;
    }
    public static Document readErnstReuterPlatzData(final Class clazz)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        final InputStream stream =
            clazz.getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("mc/ernstReuterPlatz/map.osm");
        final DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac =
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        final DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        return docBuilder.parse(stream);
    }

    private Map<String, IBuilding> composeBuildingsByIds(
        final Set<IBuilding> buildings) {
        final Map<String,IBuilding> buildingsByIds = new HashMap<>();
        for (final IBuilding building : buildings) {
            buildingsByIds.put(building.getWayId(), building);
        }
        return buildingsByIds;
    }

    private Set<IBuilding> getBuildings(final Class clazz)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
        final Document doc = readErnstReuterPlatzData(clazz);
        final PointsReader pointsReader = new PointsReader(doc);
        pointsReader.init();
        final BuildingExtractor testObject =
            new BuildingExtractor(pointsReader);
        return testObject.extractBuildings(doc);
    }
}
```

At the declaration of its only element, `INSTANCE;` I get the following compiler error in IntelliJ Idea:

```
Error:(22, 5) java: unreported exception javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

How can I fix it, given that it occurs at the line, where the **element** is defined, not a method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to throw an exception from an enum constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543903/how-to-throw-an-exception-from-an-enum-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I fix it, given that it occurs at the line, where the element is defined, not a method?

Under the hood Java creates an instance `INSTANCE` by calling the constructor. The code on the declaration line looks similar to this:

```
public static final INSTANCE = new ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings();
```

That's why the error is coming from that line.

As far as I know, there is no way to fix this by allowing the user to catch a checked exception, because `INSTANCE` is initialized in a context outside of any method call.

You can work around this issue by catching the exception yourself, and wrapping it in an unchecked `RuntimeException` of an appropriate type or even an `ExceptionInInitializerError`:

```
ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings() {
    try {
        this.buildingsByIds = composeBuildingsByIds(
            getBuildings(ErnstReuterPlatzBuildings.class)
        );
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(pce);
    } catch (SAXException sxe) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(sxe);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException xpe) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(xpe);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ioe);
    } 
}
```